# Is this a binomial or multinomial question?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-distribution

> You can donate to a company: $10$ dollars , $20$ dollars or nothing.
>
> In a mall there are $70$% young people and
>   $30$ % old people.
>
> $50$% from the old people aren't donating anything.
>
> $20$% from the young people there are donating $20$ dollars.
>
> $60$% from the people there are donating $10$ dollars.
>
> The probability that an old one donates $20$ dollars is $3/7$ times
>   smaller than the probability that a young one donates $20$ dollars.
>
> If we choose randomly, one by one, $10$ people from that mall (old and
>   young), what is the probability that exactly $7$ people donated $10$
>   dollars and the rest donated $20$ dollars?

I calculated and found that the probability for a person to donate $20$ dollars is $0.2$, and the probabilty for donating $10$ dollars is $0.6$ and for nothing is $0.2$.

My problem is that i don't know if i can use the binomial formula here such that:  $p=\binom {10}{7}0.6^70.2^3=0.02687$ or that's wrong and i need a multinomial.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability for a person to donate \$20 is not equal to 0.2.

The probability for an old person is $\frac37\cdot0.2 = \frac{3}{35}$, and the probability for a young person is 0.2. Therefore the average probability is:

$$\frac{3}{35}\cdot0.3+0.2\cdot0.7=\frac{9}{350}+\frac{14}{100}=\frac{9}{350}+\frac{49}{350}=\frac{56}{350}=\frac{4}{25}=0.16$$

Other than that, you have the right probability.

Comment: but why is it a binomial? there are three options.

Comment: @dona The multinomial coefficient and the binomial coefficient are equal, so it doesn't matter.  $${10 \choose 7,3,0} = \frac{10!}{7! 0! 3!} =  \frac{10!}{7! 3!} = {10 \choose 7}$$

Comment: i see, but basically i can say that's a multinomial question right? because we learn only the binomial and the teacher said that we can use it only if we have $2$ options but i heard there is also a multinomial but we didn't learn it.

Comment: @dona Yes, you can say that. But you would also be able to say its a binomial question.

Comment: and what will be the reason for that for someone who doesn't know what's a multinomial and knows that you can use binomial only with 2 options? sorry for asking too much..

Comment: Because you have to multiply by the number of orders to choose 7 people who pay \$10 and 3 people who pay \$20.

Comment: also, The multinomial coefficient and the binomial coefficient are equal put you need to options : $p$ and $1-p$ but here i also have a third option which i don't know how to put in the binomial formula.

Comment: No. You only have two options. The third doesn't matter. It only matters for $p$ and $q$ (not $1-p$). Your original answer was correct exepted for the miscalculated probability.